# Android ListView - Loop json_encode in PHP but only show one row in ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to take data json form PHP file that have been loop and put it into array list(ListView) in my android activity but its only show one row in Listview that is the first row from json.

Here my table that in my activity :
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KoOK.png)

Here my PHP file :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

    $nama_klp = $_POST["nama_klp"];

    $sql2 = "select id_klp from kelompok where nama_klp ='$nama_klp' ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $followingdata2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();            
    $id_klp = $followingdata2['id_klp'];

    $sql2 = "select id_mhs from praktikan where id_klp ='$id_klp' ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($con));


    while($row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $id_mhs = $row2['id_mhs'] ;


        $sql = "select nama_mhs from mahasiswa where id_mhs ='$id_mhs' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($con));

        $response = array();
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $response[] = $row ;

        }
        echo json_encode($response);


    }

?>
```

It returns a json string in this format:

```
[{"nama_mhs":"iyan2"}][{"nama_mhs":"illiyan"}][{"nama_mhs":"12"}][{"nama_mhs":"12"}]
```

Here my activity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DaftarNilaiUtama2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView LvMhs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daftar_nilai_utama2);

        TextView tvMatkul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNamaMatkul);
        TextView tvKlp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNamaKlp);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String matkul = intent.getStringExtra("matkul");
        String klp = intent.getStringExtra("klp");

        tvMatkul.setText(matkul);
        tvKlp.setText(klp);

        LvMhs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMhs);
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);


        String nama_klp = (String) tvKlp.getText();


        Response.Listener responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

                        jsonResponse = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        String nama_mhs = jsonResponse.optString("nama_mhs");
                        item.add(nama_mhs);

                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DaftarNilaiUtama2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, item);


                    LvMhs.setAdapter(adapter);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            };

            RequestLvIdMhs lvReq = new RequestLvIdMhs(nama_klp, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DaftarNilaiUtama2.this);
            queue.add(lvReq);



    }
}
```

My server request code:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by callbee on 27/05/2016.
 */
public class RequestLvIdMhs extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LvMhs_URL = "http://192.168.1.10/KartuKontrolApp/LvIdMhs-DNilaiU2.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RequestLvIdMhs(String nama_klp, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LvMhs_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("nama_klp", nama_klp);


    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

your php json string is wrong it should be like following string.

```
{"data1":[{"nama_mhs":"iyan2"}],"data2":[{"nama_mhs":"illiyan"}],"data3[{"nama_mhs":"12"}],"data4":[{"nama_mhs":"12"}]}
```

now you can pars all arrays using the respective key, for that you have to change your java code too.